# How to attribute time zones to a given UTC offset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I am trying to calculate the hour difference between pairs of UTC (known) and local timestamps, in order to find out in which timezone the local timestamps are from (this is unknown). At minimum, a reliable hour difference when compared to UTC would be needed to approximate the geographical location.

The timestamps are taken from a Pandas `DataFrame` and then converted to Pandas `datetime64`. For example:

```
date_utc_pd = pd.to_datetime(date_utc, infer_datetime_format=True)
>2020-06-28 21:00:00
date_loc_pd = pd.to_datetime(date_loc, infer_datetime_format=True)
>2020-06-28 15:00:00

tz = date_loc_pd - date_utc_pd
print(int(tz.astype("timedelta64[h]")))
> -6
```

In this example, the local timezone could be from North America, which is confirmed by domain knowledge. The solution above works for simple cases, but I doubt it can successfully handle more tricky scenarios, for example when the timestamps are on different days, DST, and such.

What is the best way to calculate the timezone offset/timezone without knowing the local timezone?

Comment: it seems you already have the calculation of the UTC offset sorted out; so the actual question would be how to attribute time zones to a given UTC offset, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that should make the question more clear. I'll rename it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this example, the local timezone could be from North America ...

Sorry, but no.  You've only determined that the offset ***for that point in time*** is UTC-6.  Since it is a date in June, it *could* be Mountain Daylight Time in the US, but it could also be Central Standard Time in parts of Canada that don't observer daylight saving time.  It could also be in Central America, such as in Belize, El Salvador, or Guatemala, or it could be in the Galapagos Islands or Easter Island.

> What is the best way to calculate the timezone offset/timezone without knowing the local timezone?

**You can't.**  From an offset alone, all you know is the offset.  You cannot determine the time zone.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

For your scenario, the best you could hope to do with a single timestamp/offset pair would be to provide a *list* of time zones that might be valid for a given timestamp and offset.  In some cases you'll only have one, but in many cases there will be multiple.

Now - if you have lots of data, all from the same time zone, across a long enough period of time, you might be able to filter the list further to *guess* at a time zone.  For example, if you know you have UTC-8 offsets in January and UTC-7 offsets in July, then you know you have Pacific Time because it's the only one that has that particular combination (in recent years).   However, you still can't tell if it's `America/Los_Angeles` (US), `America/Vancouver` (CA), or `America/Tijuana` (MX) without additional information.

However, even when you have additional information (such as the country), you may find edge cases that have ambiguous results.  One such example is the following:

```
UTC Time:   2020-11-01T06:00Z
Local Time: 2020-11-01T01:00-05:00
Offset:     UTC-5
Country:    US
```

This might be Eastern Standard Time (`America/New_York`), or it might be Central Daylight Time (`America/Chicago`).  Both are in effect simultaneously at this point in time due to how DST transitions operate in the US.  ([You can verify this here.](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20201101T060000&p1=64&p2=179&p3=1440))

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, Matt. Considering the amount of data available, and some extra user information it should be possible to generate an educated guess, or a list of time zones which fit the offset.

Comment: If you have other data to correlate, such as a lat/lon or physical address, then you can get much more precise.